# Create separate thread on application exit

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a separate thread on application exit that will continue to run (after the application closes) until the thread finishes its work?

I'm using C# and I have a case where I want to exit an application but at the same time kick off database interaction that will fire off stored procedures. My problem is that I can have a variable number of Stored Procs to execute, but I do not want to cause the application to hang or be slow to exit.

Comment: What technology are talking about? Windows Forms, WPF, Console... which one?

Comment: though not an exact answer, I can tell you it's surely possible, cause on many occasions you have it when you don't want it. Popular applications also give this behavior when they crash.

Comment: you could fire off a second process, like a console app that does this extra work, but that seems like bad design. If your application is doing work, it should be upfront about it to the user and display some sort of progress window showing the status of this final work, then exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does "application exit" mean? By definition, when the application really really exits, all its threads exit, too.

Maybe you want to start a new thread just when the UI is closed? So that the user *thinks* that the application is exited, because there is no visible UI, whereas the application still runs in the background? Yes, this is possible, but you need to tell us which UI framework are you using. (WinForms? WPF?)

Comment: I'm working with WinForms, and yes I'm referring to when the application really really exits, and it's process is terminated. Although that does bring up a good question. Would it seem reasonable to have the UI close and the process still running in background until finish?

Comment: In this case, no way. Application threads are a part of the application, so if the application exits, all the threads are terminated. Or, let's put it other way round: if any of the application threads is alive, than the application is not exited by definition.

Comment: Having UI to close and the process to run in the background is a reasonable way to achieve what you describe in the question.

Comment: Vlad, my only issue with that is on application start I check to see if it is already running. Therefore, if the user accidentally closes the app and goes to immediately re-open there is a chance they will get a message saying it is still running due to my thread executing until finish.

Comment: Yes, this is true. But it would be even worse if the 2nd instance of the application starts freely and uses the database in an inconsistent state. I would however not close the UI completely when the user closes the program, but show a small borderless window saying "finalizing the database, please wait..." during the whole database update.

Comment: Also, I thought about invoking a separate process upon application exit but I would need that process to have access to methods available in my main application. Does that sound more feasible?

Comment: IMHO starting a new process is an overkill. It's better to give the user clear idea that something is still going on. So my vision would be that the main UI closes, the program doesn't exit, but shows a small unobtrusive message instead until all the work is finished. The message window should have no frame, so the user will be unable to close it :-)

Comment: As much as I don't like it, this may be what I have to come to terms with. Only problem is I have to absolutely idiot proof this application because our users will be worldwide and I do not want support tickets/phone calls at all hours because of PEBKAC. I'll have to come up with alternatives for the application start where it checks to see if its already running...

Comment: It's quite complicated to make the application _absolutely_ idiot-proof. For example, some user may just kill your application when it's updating the data in the database, so you need to see at the next application start if some transactions are pending etc. etc.

Comment: That I have covered. It would be impossible(for this specific task) to have DB transactions pending. All data (SP's and their runtime Values) are stored in the local DB and only executed at specific events in my app. Normal DB operations are handed to SQL server as stored procs and fired off quick and dirty (for lack of better term)

Answer (score 0):

I don't want an application to continue running invisibly when I close it. This is particularly annoying when I shut down and something hangs that process up, or if I close applications to free up resources.

To be polite to your users, you should have some sort of minimizable, taskbar-visible window upon exiting that informs them of what's going on, and what the status is. This doesn't need another thread - you can do it from your exit code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does youe database support jobs?  Then all you need to do is setup the database job when your application finished.
2. If you need somekind of interaction from your program to your database, then you can consider making your application invisible when user closes the program and do the database calls that needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer again: As much as I understand it's **Windows Form** application, if you want to finish something before closing application, you can listen for your **main form's** `OnClosing` event.

By the way you **can not just proceed**, as just like **@Vlad says any thread created will be destroyed as makes a part of an application which destroyed**. So there is no other way then **block** your **main thread** and **wait other thread** and only after exit app (if you really need it, but at this point I don't think so) and finish.

Another sugession, to make "fill" to the user that application closed immediately you, may be can make form invisible and continue do your "dirty" stuff :)  But this kind of tricks are very application dependent, it's hard to me just to give you right suggession on subject.

Regards.

Comment: Tigran, after thinking about it further I realize this. However, I have to keep the mentality that my users will be morons. Therefore I do not want to leave anything open/running from my main application once exited because I dont want any adverse effects from them trying to re-open the app before I finish my "dirty work" Really just trying to further a discussion because I'm having writers block at the moment

Comment: So at this point may be the best solution is 1. Hide Window 2. Cleanup and do everything in one thread, cause you're right that they can reopen immediately again, but even if I have no idea about your application, I think it will not be ever common scenario, so for major part of cases your app will be "lightweight, fast app" :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, when the program closes, all threads are terminated.  You want to do as you mentioned in your comment on Vlad's answer.  You have to be careful about where you do the work, though.  If you do it in the `Application.ApplicationExit` event, your forms will all be disposed and you won't have access to any of the data/classes .  You're going to want to place the code in your main form's `FormClosing` event.  If you call `this.Hide()`, the form will disappear.  Execute your DB work there.  Once that method exits, the program will terminate as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the type of project, WinForm/WPF/etc, you will always be able to find a

```
static void Main(params object[] args) { ... }
```

Somewhere in your project.  It might be Program.cs or Application.cs depending on which type of project.  In this there will be the call that opens the UI of your application, which is a blocking call.  Anything you put into that Main is going to be executed after your UI exits, has closed its windows, etc.